# How to pass/send path parameters to Lambda from an AWS ALB event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to access my Lambda from an AWS ALB (application load balancer). While I am able to pass query string parameters along with the request and get the values in the event object generated for the alb event, is it possible to pass path parameters and extract them in lambda ? If so what's the right approach? Thanks.

Ref for event object from alb - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html

Comment: I think you will need to just parse them out of the `path` string in the `event` object.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers/ have you try this ?